# Installing VMware Player 12 bundle on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vmware-workstation

I have downloaded VMware Workstation Player 12 but it came as a bundle.  I've tried running it from the CLI but it keeps telling me to take a hike.  How do I install this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your CLI, change to the directory that the bundle is in:

```
cd <dirname>
```

Make the bundle executable

```
chmod +x VMware-Workstation-Full-12.0.1-3160714.x86_64.bundle
```

Execute the bundle

```
sudo sh ./VMware-Workstation-Full-12.0.1-3160714.x86_64.bundle
```

Now VMWare is installed, but there is a bug! Still in the terminal, enter

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
vmware
```

VMWare should start.  To make the change 'permanent', execute 'sudo nano /usr/bin/vmware' and add the line

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1
```

after the line export PRODUCT_NAME...

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit: VMWare will now work.

To perform the same function for VMPlayer, execute the same changes to /usr/bin/vmplayer

Comment: Of course, chmod to make it executable.  I'm so new to this.  Thanks.

Comment: Di Nada - you may not have had a problem with the weird export variable.  I think this is primarily a problem with Ubuntu 15.10